# How to change the colour of unread emails (subject and body) in outlook 2010?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

I can change the colour of the the sender and subject using conditional formatting for unread emails. But I would actually like all of the message to change colour in my reading pane. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you looking for this option? [color](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/fontsizecolor.htm)

Answer (score 1):

On the **View** tab, in the **Current View group**, click **View Settings.**

In the **Advanced View Settings** dialog box, click **Conditional Formatting.**

A set of default rules appears. This includes the **Unread messages** rule. This rule makes unread messages appear bold in the message list. In addition, any conditional formatting rules that you created in the **Organize** pane with an earlier version of Outlook appear.

Do any of the following:

To delete a rule, click the rule, and then click **Delete**.

To temporarily turn off a rule, clear the check box for that rule.

To change the criteria for a rule, click the rule, and then click **Condition**.

To change the text formatting, click the rule, and then click **Font**.

To add a new conditional formatting rule, click **Add**, in the **Name** box, type a name, click **Font** to specify the formatting, and then click **Condition** to specify the criteria for this rule.

**Example conditional formatting rules**